# Sum of array, fetched data from database

Tags: javascript, arrays

I used json to send prices over.
How do i sum all the numbers in this array?

```
 arr[i].itemPrice
```

I have tried this but i am only getting the second value and not the total

```
for (var i =0; i<arr.length;i++){
sum += arr[i].itemPrice;
alert(sum);
}
```

Comment: Please be careful with how you tag your question.  If your question is about [tag:javascript], there is little benefit to you in attracting [tag:java] experts to your question.

Comment: You can move `alert` outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Array's `reduce` function (ES6):

```
const sum = arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.itemPrice, 0);
```

The `reduce` function allows you to iterate over a collection and accumulate the elements data however you'd like.

Comment: The numbers i have are 78.00 and 80.00. But it comes out as 078.0080.00, any idea why?

Comment: Are the numbers saved as strings? Because it looks like string concatenation

Comment: If it's a string, you can change `el.itemPrice` to `Number(el.itemPrice)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   sum += arr[i].itemPrice;
}
alert(sum);
```

Alert the sum after the loop completes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `array` is something like below , you can use `Array.reduce` for this

```js
let arr = [{ itemPrice: 1}, { itemPrice: 2}, { itemPrice: 3}]

console.log(arr.reduce((a, {itemPrice}) => a + itemPrice, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)

```js
const data = [{itemPrice:20.00}, {itemPrice:15.00}, {itemPrice:25.00}];

const total = data.reduce((sum, {itemPrice})=>sum+itemPrice, 0);

console.log(total);
```